# Can I save only one DomElement to jpg use DotNetBrowser?

Tags: c#, dotnetbrowser

in Documentations, I find How to save the full page - [link to article](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000125134-saving-web-page-to-png-image-in-offscreen-mode)

but for me need save only one element from page to jpg
It's really?
How can I do it with `DotNetBrowser`?

Answer (score 0):

DotNetBrowser does not provide an API which allows saving the specific `DomElement` as a JPG.

However, if you need to save resources (such as images, favicons, etc.) from the webpage, take a look at the `Browser.Context.NetworkService.ResourceHandler` interface. Here is a code snippet:

```
class SampleResourceHandler : ResourceHandler
{
    public bool CanLoadResource(ResourceParams parameters)
    {
        if (parameters.ResourceType == ResourceType.IMAGE)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("image URL: " + parameters.URL);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This article contains more information about [how to handle resources loading](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/solution/articles/9000110154-handling-resources-loading)

Comment: sometimes foto in the page has the capacity, but with background good visible, and for this situation need save some div which have png and background - for example. I think, that if we can save all page with concrete size - maybe we can save some coordinates and size concrete DomElement from a page

Comment: sometimes src atributte have not url but base64 - for exemple

Comment: It is possible to save a web page with concrete size: Browser.ImageProvider.GetImage(viewWidth, viewHeight); For this purpose, you should use lightweight rendering mode.